# How to load a specific storyboard depending on size of screen

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, uistoryboard

I am trying to develop an app to be compatible with the 3.5 inch as well as the 4 inch displays. However when I try to use auto layout I can not figure out how to resize the views depending on the size of the screen. The only other way I can imagine going around this is to design two storyboards and load one depending on the size of the screen of the phone. Can someone help me out with this? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AutoLayout can't target specific models of iPhone. However, there is a workaround for that. You have two options.

### First option

Place an invisible `UIView` and create top, bottom, leading and trailing constraints come ted with the `Superview`. After that place your objects (they can be `UIImageViews`, `UILabels` and the list goes on) inside the `UIView` you have just placed. Now create top and bottom constraints that connect your objects to the `UIView`.

I created a demo to show you how it's done. As you will see, buttons have different sizes depending on the screen's size. Download the demo from [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/aecn78q6bsyb06g/Demo.zip?dl=0) link.

### Second option

You could create and modify constraints programmatically. Create a `NSLayoutConstraint` and adjust the `constant` of it depending on the user's device:

```
var myConstant: CGFloat = 0

if UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height == 480 {
        // iPhone 4
    myConstant = 10
    } else if UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height == 568 {
        // iPhone 5
    myConstant = 20
    } else if UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width == 375 {
        // iPhone 6
    myConstant = 30
    } else if UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width == 414 {
        // iPhone 6+
    myConstant = 40
    } else if UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width == 768 {
        // iPad
    myConstant = 50
    }

var myConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint (item: myButton,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top,
        relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
        toItem: self.view,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top,
        multiplier: 1,
        constant: myConstant)
    self.view.addConstraint(myConstraint)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [size classes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/_index.html) on the storyboard. You can specify other layouts of the same components, using the same code on different devices.

If you really want to use different storyboards, set it in AppDelegate in the method `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`. Here you can get the screen size by

```
self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
```

and set the storyboard using

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
window!.rootViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("InitVC") as UIViewController
window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

This code will instantiate the app with the storyboard `Main` and the initial view controller `InitVC`